# Manipulating csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, module

I would like to select some data thanks to a condition in a csv file and write it in anoter csv file organized differently, and them then select another data and write it in the other file again on the same line. I use the csv module and the function writerow to do that :

```
#Creation of the other csv file 
with open('superAdmins.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    spamwriter.writerow(['SuperAdmins'] + ['2 step authentication'] + ['Portée des droits'])

i = 0



#Selection of the first data 
with open('admins.csv', 'r') as csvinput,open('2authentication.csv', 'r') as csvinput2, open('superAdmins.csv', 'w+') as csvoutput:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvinput, delimiter=',') #lecteur
    reader2 = csv.DictReader(csvinput2, delimiter=',') #lecteur 

    fieldnames = ['SuperAdmins', '2 step authentication','Portée des droits']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvoutput,fieldnames = fieldnames) #crayon 

    writer.writeheader()  #Ecrit l'en-tête avec les fieldnames

    for row in reader:
        # write the selection logic here
        if row["role"] == "_SEED_ADMIN_ROLE":
            writer.writerow({'SuperAdmins': row['assignedToUser']})


#Selection of the second data
        for row in reader:
            print(row["primaryEmail"],superadmin)
            # write the selection logic here
            if row["primaryEmail"] == superadmin:
                if row["isEnforcedIn2Sv"] == "False" and row["isEnrolledIn2Sv"] == "False":
                    writer.writerow({'2 step authentication': "false"})
```

I get :

```
SuperAdmins,2 step authentication,Portée des droits
julientest@w-cdt.xyz,,
,Test,
,false,
```

Whereas I would like to have :

```
SuperAdmins,2 step authentication,Portée des droits
julientest@w-cdt.xyz,Test,false
```

I guess that the function writerow starts a new line by adding a comma at each use, I'm looking for a way to keep writing on the same line.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The 'writerow' method writes a full row. So when you have multiple cells in a row you need to write the whole row only once (not twice as you are doing now).

The simple solution would be to define a variable (maybe called row_dict), fill it gradually with all the info and then at the end of the loop use the writerow function with the variable as argument.

On your specific code:

```
for row in reader:
    row_dict = {}
    # write the selection logic here
    if row["role"] == "_SEED_ADMIN_ROLE":
        row_dict['SuperAdmins'] = row['assignedToUser']

        print(row["primaryEmail"],superadmin)
        # write the selection logic here
        if row["primaryEmail"] == superadmin:
            if row["isEnforcedIn2Sv"] == "False" and row["isEnrolledIn2Sv"] == "False":
                row_dict['2 step authentication'] = ["false"]

    writer.writerow(row_dict)
```

Comment: this should be a comment unless you are willing to provide some code that is relevant to OPs question

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry I'm starting to learn Python and I have never used a "row_dict variable". I don't understand the info about it online, may I ask you how it works ?

Comment: It works perfect, thank you very much @lesingerouge !
I would like to understand, what is the type of the dic_variable ? It is a dictionnary ? Is it part of the csv module ?

Comment: @KB303 the 'row_dict' variable is just a dictionary that will hold the values that you are looking to select from the whole existing row.